# Using variable as identifier in object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, identifier

I have a code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.Table.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {                           
        var xIndex = 'F' + (x + 1)
        var item = result.Table[i].xIndex;
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I can't use xIndex in example as this. So how to change script to be able to set xIndex as identifier?

Thanks.

Comment: Same way you use `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the dot syntax there, just use brackets and it'll work

```
result.Table[i][xIndex]
```

Comment: I'm stupid, it was so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: It's okay :p these kind of frustrating little bugs happen all the time.